# Awk to extract and format a highly variable text file

Tags: regex, awk, delimiter

I'm dealing with a text file that's just a mess. It's the service record for a used RV that I'm buying, and it's a regex lover's nightmare

It has both inconsistent field separators and an inconsistent number of fields, with the lines being one of two types:

```
Type 1 (11 columns):
UNIT   Mile  GnHr  R.O. Ln  Service  Description                Mechanic   Hours  $ Amt
7-9918;57878 1698 01633 021;0502-00C ENG OIL/ FILTERT IF NEEDED;M02 JOSE A. SANCHEZ;0.80;80.00

Type 2 (10 columns)
UNIT   Mile  GnHr  R.O. Ln  Service  Description   Hours  $ Amt
7-9918;55007 1641 [9564 007;ELE-BAT-BAT-0-0AAA;BATTERY AAA ALL BRANDS;2;31.12
```

I've stripped out all the headings, but put them back here just for reference. In Type 2 lines, the Mechanic field is missing.

I replaced all occurrences of multiple spaces with semicolons, so what I have now is a file where some lines have 10 fields, some lines have 11 fields, and sometimes the field separator is a space, and in other cases it's a semicolon, and some fields have legitimate embedded spaces (Description and Mechanic).

I'm trying to find a way with awk to:

1) Extract each field and be able to print it out with a uniform OFS (semicolon is preferred)

2) If the Mechanic field is missing, insert it and print N/A or -- for the Mechanic

I can deal with column headings and stuff myself, I just can't crack the code for how to deal with the FS problem and variable number of columns in this file. I can grep out specific information that I need, but would be thrilled to get it into a form where I can import it into a spreadsheet or DB.

Comment: We are here to help with your codes, so please provide some code you have tried.

Comment: It sounds like you need to find some indicator to tell you whether a row has 11 fields or 10, and then filter lines based on that before you can process them. Given how variable the data is, you will probably be better off writing something simple in Python or Perl to express what you're trying to do and clean up the data, rather than a column-oriented tool like awk.

Comment: @merlin2011 sounds like you've never used awk. Maybe heard rumors or seen a couple of very trivial or very bad examples but never actually used it. There is nothing you could do in Perl or Python that you couldn't do in awk for a problem like this.

Comment: @edmorton I am not a heavy user of awk. I generally use it when the data is cleanly delimited and switch to python when it gets messy. I also did not claim it was impossible in awk, only less natural. :)

Comment: @merlin2011 you're happy using python and there's nothing wrong with that, but for manipulating text, complicated or otherwise, awk is every bit as effective as any other tool, usually results in clearer code than most AND it comes as standard on every UNIX installation. Advocate python or perl if you like but its just plain wrong to suggest that people would in some way be better of using those than awk for text manipulation. If you feel that python would be better than awk for this problem then please do feel free to post a python solution so we can compare it to the awk one I posted.

Comment: @user54708, Please accept Ed Morton's solution if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file's not so bad. Assuming your input file is semi-colon separated:

1. Replace all blank chars in `$2` with a `;` to split that up into separate fields for output, then
2. if there's a blank in `$3` then replace the first blank with a `;` (since it contains both the service and description so you need to separate them), otherwise
3. this is a format of line that has no mechanic specified so add the empty-mechanic text after `$4` (the description)

and then just print the line:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {gsub(/ /,OFS,$2)} !sub(/ /,OFS,$3){$4=$4 OFS "N/A"} 1' file
7-9918;57878;1698;01633;021;0502-00C;ENG OIL/ FILTERT IF NEEDED;M02 JOSE A. SANCHEZ;0.80;80.00
7-9918;55007;1641;[9564;007;ELE-BAT-BAT-0-0AAA;BATTERY AAA ALL BRANDS;N/A;2;31.12
```

and if you'd like to do anything with the individual fields:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
{ gsub(/ /,OFS,$2) }
!sub(/ /,OFS,$3) { $4 = $4 OFS "N/A" }
{
    $0 = $0
    print
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        print NR, i, $i
    }
    print ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
7-9918;57878;1698;01633;021;0502-00C;ENG OIL/ FILTERT IF NEEDED;M02 JOSE A. SANCHEZ;0.80;80.00
1;1;7-9918
1;2;57878
1;3;1698
1;4;01633
1;5;021
1;6;0502-00C
1;7;ENG OIL/ FILTERT IF NEEDED
1;8;M02 JOSE A. SANCHEZ
1;9;0.80
1;10;80.00

7-9918;55007;1641;[9564;007;ELE-BAT-BAT-0-0AAA;BATTERY AAA ALL BRANDS;N/A;2;31.12
2;1;7-9918
2;2;55007
2;3;1641
2;4;[9564
2;5;007
2;6;ELE-BAT-BAT-0-0AAA
2;7;BATTERY AAA ALL BRANDS
2;8;N/A
2;9;2
2;10;31.12
```

Comment: I will write a Python answer if he accepts this answer, because it is not clear to me that his examples captures the nuances of his problem sufficiently. That is why I did not originally write an answer. Also, I do appreciate learning more awk from this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine also sent me this solution, done in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

#                                                                                                     1         1         1         1         1
#           1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         0         1         2         3         4
# 012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
# Type 1:
# 7-9918  55007 1641 [9564 022            0211     INTERIOR MISC.                  M02 JOSE A. SANCHEZ                0.00       0.00
# Type 2:
# 7-9918  57878 1698 01633 001            FUE-LPG-LPG-S-GAS      PROPANE GAS BULK PURCHASE                             5        24.00

my $delim="\t";

while (<STDIN>) {
    #print $_;

    # Both formats are the same at this point
    print substr($_, 0, 6) . $delim;
    print substr($_, 8, 5) . $delim;
    print substr($_, 14, 4) . $delim;
    print substr($_, 19, 5) . $delim;
    print substr($_, 25, 3) . $delim;

    my $qty = substr($_, 109, 11);
    $qty =~ s/^\s*//g;
    $qty =~ s/\s*$//g;

    if ($qty =~ /^\d+\.\d{2}$/) {
        # Type 1
        print substr($_, 40, 9) . $delim;
        print substr($_, 49, 32) . $delim;
        # print substr($_, 81, 32) . $delim; # Technician name
        print $qty . $delim;
    } elsif ($qty =~ /^[-]?\d+$/) {
        # Type 2
        print substr($_, 40, 23) . $delim;
        print substr($_, 63, 46) . $delim;
        print $qty . $delim;
    }
    print sprintf("%.2f", substr($_, 120, 11)) . "\n";
}

1;
```